# "Vector iterator not incrementable" error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I added coin system to my cocos2d-x c++ game. I have a problem.
I want to auto release coin groups when they go out of sight. I mean, if a coin group slides through the scene and exits the scene, i want to destroy it. How to do that?

Like this:

```
for (auto gr : coinGroups) {
    gr->setPositionX(gr->getPositionX() - scrollSpeed);

    if(gr->getBoundingBox().getMaxX() < origin.x) {
        this->removeChild(gr);
        coinGroups.erase(coinGroups.begin());
    }
}
```

coinGroups is a

```
std::vector<CoinGroup*>
```

But this gives me error (“vector iterator not incrementable” bla bla bla).

How can I solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: `coinGroups.erase(coinGroups.begin())` imvalidates the iteratores used by the range based for loop.

Comment: You can't erase in a range based iteration since you invalidate the current iterator and have no way to assign the value of erase back to the current iterator. Use a real iterator loop or an idiom like remove/erase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not delete elements from a container where you traverse through, because this would cause an undefined behavior.
Note the loop uses an internal iterator.

The following code is only to better understand the issue, but you would have to do something like that:

```
std::vector<CoinGroup*> tempCoins;
tempCoins.swap( coinGroups );
for (auto gr : tempCoins)
{
    .....

    if(gr->getBoundingBox().getMaxX() < origin.x)
        this->removeChild(gr);
    else
        coinGroups.push_back(gr)
}
```

The common solution in c++ is to use [`std::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/):

```
#include <algorithm> // std::remove_if

auto endIt = std::remove_if( coinGroups.begin(), coinGroups.end(), [&](CoinGroup *gr) -> bool
{
    gr->setPositionX(gr->getPositionX() - scrollSpeed);
    if (gr->getBoundingBox().getMaxX() < origin.x)
    {
        this->removeChild(gr);
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
} );
coinGroups.erase(endIt, coinGroups.end());
```

Comment: @ZanLynx remove_if doesn't change the order of the remaining elements

Comment: @Caleth: Huh. You're right. Must have been a different library's remove function I was thinking of. The one I was remembering swapped the removed element with the last element. So it never had to shift anything in the rest of the range.

Comment: It looks like `std::partition` can do that in the standard algorithms library.

Comment: @ZanLynx Oh, I think we meant the same, but we have passed each other.